# Redux form - clearFields not working with initialized values

Tags: redux-form

I am trying to clear some fields in my form, but I noticed it is not working when the values our initialized previously. 
I am initializing values if there is any data coming from the backend:

```
const initialValues = (actionPoint) => {
    if (!actionPoint) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return values = {
      isTheRepaymentChosen: repayment.chosen,
      options: repayment.option.code,
      reason: actionPoint.reason,
    };
};
```

And on changing values on my radio buttons, I am firing a method where I am clearing fields:

```
resetFields() {
    const { formPrefix, clearFields: clearFormFields } = this.props;
    const fields = ['isTheRepaymentChosen', 'options', 'reason'];
    clearFormFields(`${formPrefix}.${formName}`, false, false, ...fields);
  }
```

This is working fine when I don't get any data from the backend and beacuse of that not building any intial values. Then the fields are always cleared on changing values of the radio buttons. But, when I get data and build initial values, then the fields are not being cleared. 
Is there any workaround or fix for this?